# regular expression to match Number + string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match these use cases in Javascript:
a) `8 Months`
b) `18 Years`

Numbers could range from 1 to 20 and the strings could only be either "months" or "years"

I am trying this

```
[0-9]\s(Years|Months)
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Try [0-9]+\s(Years|Months)
+ will make RE to accept atleast 1 number.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\s(Years|Months)
```

where:

- `[1-9]` matches a digit from 1 to 9
- `1[0-9]` matches a number from 10 to 19
- `20` matches just 20

**Edit**: As noticed in a comment, you should use

```
^([1-9]|1[0-9]|20)\s(Years|Months)$
```

if the whole string must exactly match with this text.

Another option is prepending the regex with a word boundary (`\b`) in order to prevent matching cases like "42 Years".

Comment: Note that this regex still matches `2 Years` in the text `42 Years`, depending on the context of OP you (the reader of the answer) might want to anchor the regex to the start `^` and end `$` of the string or use a negative lookbehind to make sure the character before the match is not a number.

Comment: @3limin4t0r Thank you, I updated the answer mentioning also the word boundary.